# How could Drago fly on Toothless?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon-2

How could Drago fly on Toothless, when he didn't know about the mechanism in his tail? Only Hiccup knew how to fly on him, and here's Drago sitting on Toothless? I can't understand that.

Comment: Do you have an image you can include? Google didn't return any that I could see. My search was "Drago Riding Toothless".